# Unable to click on date from calendar popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to click the date from calendar popup which is inside iframe.  I have written below selenium code which throwing unable to locate the element error. Please help me to write correct xpath or selenium code. I am  new to Selenium

selenium code:

```
WebElement iframe =driver.findElement(By.id("NewsSearchDateToInput_selector_iframe"));

driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
//clicking on date 3  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='daysNumbersStyles']")).click();
```

> Error:  unable to locate the element "//div[3][@class='daysNumbersStyles']"

Html tags:

```
<iframe id="NewsSearchDateToInput_selector_iframe" 
        class="dateTimeSelectorContainerStyle altFlexibleContainer" 
        src="javascript:false;" 
        style="left: 1216px; top: 245px; width: 249px; height: 207px; 
               display: block;"/>

<div class="dateTimeSelectorContainerStyle altFlexibleContainer" 
     style="top: 245px; left: 1216px; display: block;">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="dateSelectorHeader">
        <div class="dateSelectorBody">
          <div class="yearMonthSelectorStyle">
            <div id="NewsSearchDateToInput_selector_monthSelector" class="monthSelectorListStyle">
              <div class="daysStyle">
                <div>
                  <div class="daysNumbersDivStyle">
                    <div class="daysNumbersStyles">1</div>
                      <div class="daysNumbersStyles">2</div>
                        <div class="daysNumbersStyles">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

does it help ? //div[@class='daysNumbersStyles'][3]

Comment: Its finding two elements, 1 for FromDate calendar and 2nd for ToDate calendar.

Comment: you can modify a bit //div[@id='FromDate']//div[@class='daysNumbersStyles'][3] something like that

Comment: Looks like its not switching to frame itself. iframe able find during the xpath expression but not in webdriver.  Any other way we can switch to frame?

Comment: post your code, and we can help you. Basically you need to always switch from frame to default to frame something like that. driver.switchTo();

Answer (score 0):

Try this after getting in to frame:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='3']").click();
```

Edit:

For To selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='NewsSearchDateToInput_selector_monthSelector']//div[text()='3']").click();
```

For From selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='NewsSearchDateFromInput_selector_monthSelector']//div[text()='3']").click();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. but xpath you mentioned is finding two element  one for FromDate and other one for ToDate calendar.  I have id for FromDate and ToDate , how i can use the id along with above xpath to find the element.                     {id='NewsSearchDateFromInput_selector_monthSelector}    {NewsSearchDateToInput_selector_monthSelector}

Comment: error Unable to locate element. I think its not finding the iframe itself.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. element is not under the iframe,its outside the frame.